# React list.map() renders twice

Tags: reactjs, render

I would like to display a dashboard with a simple list of items when I click on a button. The application uses React.

I added some `console.log()` inside the render, when `items.map()` is executed and I notice that the console.log() appear twice.

The code is provided [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-surf-mlrce).

I wondering why it renders twice. Do you know what happens please ? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not related to `map()` or any other implementation feature. This is related to work of `StrictMode` in development. This was explained by Dan Abramov [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/15074#issuecomment-471197572).

You can remove `<StrictMode>` from your `index.js` and see this effect disappears.

And this won't affect your application in production build.

Comment: OK. Thank you for your answer. How are we supposed to distinguish an effect from StrictMode from an actual wrong behaviour in an application ?

Comment: I think, you might use your `console.log` inside `shouldComponentUpdate()` instead of `render()` (or inside `useEffect()` if you're using react hooks).